# Predict.glm returns negative probability?

Tags: r

I want to estimate the probability from a logistic regression model.

```
model <- glm(pheno~best.pgs, data = pgs.res)
summary(model)
prob <- predict(model, pgs.res, type = 'response')
```

But it returns several negative probabilities and probabilities greater than 1.

```
summary(prob)
   Min.  1st Qu. Median   Mean   3rd Qu.    Max. 
-0.1933  0.3865  0.4988  0.4999  0.6139  1.1687
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default for `glm` is just a normal linear regression. If you want to fit a logistic model you need to add `family=binomial()` to the `glm()` call. Try

```
model <- glm(pheno~best.pgs, data = pgs.res, family=binomial())
```